# Load the data into the grid using json object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dhtmlx

I have created a grid using DHTMLX.I retreived the data from the data base using linq.and I am able to display the data in the output.but these are not loading into the grid.Now i want to load the data into the grid using JSON object.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score -1):

Here is online sample about your question. I think it must help you:

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/12_initialization_loading/09_init_grid_json.html

JSON syntax is the next:

```
data = {
    rows: [{
        id: 1001,
        data: ["100", "A Time to Kill", "John Grisham", "12.99", "1", "05/01/1998"]
        }, {
        id: 1002,
        data: ["1000", "Blood and Smoke", "Stephen King", "0", "1", "01/01/2000"]
        }, {
        id: 1003,
        data: ["-200", "The Rainmaker", "John Grisham", "7.99", "0", "12/01/2001"]
        }, {
        id: 1004,
        data: ["350", "The Green Mile", "Stephen King", "11.10", "1", "01/01/1992"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post snippets or a summary of the solution. A link-only answer is discourage here, because it can turn obsolete.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).